# IExcelReader how to read date and insert it into sql?

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, excel-reader

I have in my excel some date fields that are in this format:
1/4/2016, 2/14/2016, etc.
When i try to insert that fields in a database I get an error:
String is not recongized as a valid DateTime

this is my code:

```
 IExcelDataReader excelReader;
                if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(ope.FileName).ToUpper() == ".XLS")
                {

                    excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream,true);
                }
                else
                {

                    excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
                }

                excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
                DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet(true);

                DataClassesFinPodaciDataContext conn = new DataClassesFinPodaciDataContext();

                foreach (DataRow dr in result.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                   string s1 = Convert.ToString(dr[4]);
                    DateTime conv1 = Convert.ToDateTime(s1);
                    string d2 = Convert.ToString(dr[14]);
                    DateTime conv2 = Convert.ToDateTime(d2);
                    string d3 = Convert.ToString(dr[15]);
                    DateTime conv3 = Convert.ToDateTime(d3);
                    string d4 = Convert.ToString(dr[19]);
                    DateTime conv4 = Convert.ToDateTime(d4);

                    //string d1 = string.Parse()
                    tblFinansijskiPodaci addTable = new tblFinansijskiPodaci()
                    {

                        Firma = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]),
                        NazFirme = Convert.ToString(dr[1]),
                        VrstaNal = Convert.ToString(dr[2]),
                        BrojNal = Convert.ToInt32(dr[3]),
                        DatumNal = conv1,
                        SifraRJ = Convert.ToInt32(dr[5]),
                        Konto = Convert.ToString(dr[6]),
                        NazivKonta = Convert.ToString(dr[7]),
                        Partner = Convert.ToInt32(dr[8]),
                        NazivPartnera = Convert.ToString(dr[9]),
                        Adresa = Convert.ToString(dr[10]),
                        Mesto = Convert.ToString(dr[11]),
                        PIB = Convert.ToString(dr[12]),
                        BrojDok = Convert.ToString(dr[13]),
                        DatumDok = conv2,
                        DatumVal = conv3,
                        Opis = Convert.ToString(dr[16]),
                        Duguje = Convert.ToInt32(dr[17]),
                        Potrazuje = Convert.ToInt32(dr[18]),
                        DatumZaPDV = conv4,
                        Valuta = Convert.ToString(dr[20]),
                        DevDuguje = Convert.ToInt32(dr[21]),
                        DevPotrazuje = Convert.ToInt32(dr[22]),
                        Oslob = Convert.ToInt32(dr[23]),
                        IznosPDV = Convert.ToInt32(dr[24]),
                        Oslob1 = Convert.ToInt32(dr[25]),
                        IznosOslob = Convert.ToInt32(dr[26]),
                        UvozOsnovica = Convert.ToInt32(dr[27])

                    };
                    //   conn.ExecuteCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE Excel");
                    //  conn.ExecuteCommand("DELETE FROM tblFinansijskiPodaci where ime='a'");
                    conn.tblFinansijskiPodacis.InsertOnSubmit(addTable);

                }

                conn.SubmitChanges();
                excelReader.Close();
```

I have also tried

```
double d = double.Parse(Convert.ToString(dr[4])); DateTime conv = DateTime.FromOADate(d);
```

but that didnt work,since, I think since my date is not in a only numbers format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse your dates specifiying the input format of dates to parse.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("1/4/2016", "d/M/yyyy);
```